# Is there any way to get schema.org RDF in slices?

Tags: rdf, owl, schema.org

I was wondering if it is possible to not load the whole schema.org ontology so as to use it with the GoodRelations ontology, in a way that would involve OWL DL reasoning.

I do not want to get the whole vocabulary, I want just a slice of it. For instance the product type ontology is as such but that ontology does not suit my needs.

Comment: I don't understand.  Just use the types that you want.

Comment: Well i want to use it in the context of OWL-DL, meaning i have to import the type with its ontology. If you try the product type ontology it is modularized. When you dereference the URI of a book for instance you only get an ontology that contain the class book only: http://www.productontology.org/id/Book (Accept: rdf+xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Ontology modularization is a non-trivial task. In a nutshell, it is easy only if the creator of the ontology implements it at design time. The reason is that there can be complex dependencies between the axioms for the various conceptual elements.

I designed www.productontology.org specifically in this way so that one can use only the subset of axioms related to a single class. I am not aware of any other broadly used ontology that uses the same pattern.

This having said, what you can do is use any of the OWL transcriptions of schema.org:

- http://topbraid.org/schema/ (pretty good IMO)
- http://schema.rdfs.org/ (RDFS only)
- http://schema.org/docs/schemaorg.owl (outdated - not for production use)

and extract only the type definition and the necessary property axioms. This could be done in a Python script or similar.

Another approach is to take the RDFa version of the current vocabulary

- http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html

and manually generate class and property declarations in OWL for the types that you need. The patterns would be similar to those found in www.productontology.org.